# ionic 2 create adapter like android?

Tags: android, angular, firebase, ionic2, firebaseui

Since 1 week i have started with ionic2 and angular2 , because i wanted to develop for android and ios at the same time. I have written a Chat application for android in Java and now i would like to write this application new in Ionic2.
But i have one problem , namely the adapter. I have in Java an Adapter like this

```
public class ChatFirebaseAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatModel, ChatFirebaseAdapter.MyChatViewHolder> {

private static final int RIGHT_MSG = 0;
private static final int RIGHT_MSG_LOW = 7;
private static final int LEFT_MSG = 1;
private static final int LEFT_MSG_LOW = 6;
private static final int RIGHT_MSG_IMG = 2;
private static final int LEFT_MSG_IMG = 3;

public ChatFirebaseAdapter(DatabaseReference ref, String nameUser, String IdUser, ClickListenerChatFirebase mClickListenerChatFirebase, Context context, ContentResolver cr, String id) {
    super(ChatModel.class, R.layout.item_message_left, ChatFirebaseAdapter.MyChatViewHolder.class, ref);
    this.nameUser = nameUser;
    this.idUser = IdUser;
    this.mClickListenerChatFirebase = mClickListenerChatFirebase;
    this.context = context;
    this.cr = cr;
    this.groupID = id;

}

@Override
public MyChatViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view;
    if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == LEFT_MSG) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_left_single, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG_IMG) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_img, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == LEFT_MSG_IMG) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_left_img, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == RIGHT_EMJI) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_emji, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else if (viewType == RIGHT_MSG_LOW) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_right_low, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    } else {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_messages_left_low, parent, false);
        return new MyChatViewHolder(view);
    }
}
```

And populate viewholder and so on..

And i use a Model :

```
public class ChatModel {

private String id;
private String user;
private String username;
private String userphoto;
private boolean send;
private boolean delivered;
private boolean seen;
private boolean isEmji;
private String userModel;
private String message;
private String timeStamp;
private FileModel file;
private MapModel mapModel;

public ChatModel() {
}

public ChatModel(String senderID, String message, String timeStamp, FileModel file, boolean send, boolean delivered , boolean seen ,String ID , String username , String userphoto , Boolean isEmji) {
    this.userModel = senderID;
    this.message = message;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.file = file;
    this.send = send;
    this.id = ID;
    this.username = username;
    this.userphoto =  userphoto;
    this.isEmji = isEmji;
    this.delivered = delivered;
    this.seen = seen;

}

public ChatModel(String senderID, String timeStamp, MapModel mapModel, boolean send, boolean delivered , boolean seen , String ID , String username , String userphoto , Boolean isEmji) {
    this.userModel = senderID;
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.mapModel = mapModel;
    this.send = send;
    this.id = ID;
    this.username = username;
    this.userphoto = userphoto;
    this.isEmji = isEmji;
    this.delivered = delivered;
    this.seen = seen;

} ....
```

On Android I create a new Instance and apply the adapter :

```
        final ListUserFirebaseAdapter firebaseAdapter = new ListUserFirebaseAdapter(mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child("users/" + id + "/Chats/").orderByChild("lastTimeStamp").getRef(), name, id , getActivity() ,this , getContext());

        rvListMessage.setAdapter(firebaseAdapter);
```

How can i now do this on ionic 2 ? I cannot find any suggestion on the Internet :(

Hopefully you can help me :)
(Sry for my bad english i´m from germany :|)

MFG Cem

Answer (score 0):

FirebaseUI is available for Android, iOS and a more limited version for the (plain JavaScript) web. There is no FirebaseUI library for Angular2. It also wouldn't make a lot of sense, since the underlying model of Angular2 is *quite* different from the models of iOS and Android.

But you can use [AngularFire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2), which is the equally official library for Angular2.

Comment: Yes i have it already implemented but i cant display the data without the models and adapter or ?

Comment: In that case, share the code using AngularFire2 that you're having trouble with. It'll make it a lot easier to help.

Comment: export const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "__",
    authDomain: "__",
    databaseURL: "__",
    storageBucket: "__",
    messagingSenderId: "__"
};

Comment: that works and now here to diplay :   songs: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
this.songs = af.database.list('/songs'); but the problem is i use in java a model for that how can i do this here ?

Comment: <ion-content padding>
 <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let song of songs | async"(click)="showOptions(song.$key, song.title)">
    {{song.title}}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>

Comment: Please add this to your question. In fact, you might want to consider if this code isn't more of what you're asking for: why doesn't this code work Angular2/AngularFire2 code work? If that's the question, the Android code isn't needed (as far as I can tell).